the name of the made-for-tv-movie where the kid gets his house broken into?
I'm looking for a movie that I watched on TV when I was a kid sometime in the mid 90s and I have never been able to find the title of it. I don't remember if it was a made-for-tv movie, or just a re-run of a regular movie. But I definitely saw it on TV. I didn't rent it or anything. 
I just remember there was a boy (I thought it might be Jonathan Brandis, but I can't find it on his Wikipedia page, but when I try to picture the starring actor of the movie his face keeps popping up in my head, so perhaps it was another 90s kid actor similar to Jonathan Brandis.) From what I remember there was this boy (maybe like 11-14yrs old) and he stayed home from school (sick or something), and then like 2 badguys broke into his home. Similar to the Home Alone movies, but WITHOUT the comedy. To a kid my age it was actually quite terrifying. I remember there being a pet parrot in it too and I remember the kid shooting them at the end with his Dad's gun from his dresser or closet.

Pretty sure the movie you are looking for is Armed and Innocent (1994).



According to the synopsis on Wikipedia:

An 11-year-old boy, Chris Holland, is left at home alone after school.
  When three robbers invade their home, Chris uses a .22 rifle to shoot
  and kill two of them. The third, who escaped, and their imprisoned
  leader, Earl, hopes to get revenge on Chris who is traumatized by the
  incident.

This scene shows a parrot making a lot of noise while they are breaking in:




That is it!!wow thats amazing.thank you

now i just have to find a site to download it free on my tablet
